Графики Grafana на странице в django
подскажите как добавить один из графиков Grafana в на верстку в django используя сервисный аккаунт Grafana.

Вроде бы народ подключал как-то в веб-страницу gui от grafana через api-key, но чтоб отдельный график - этого мне не известно.

@strawdog, не могу найти инфу как подключится через api

https://grafana.com/blog/2023/10/10/how-to-embed-grafana-dashboards-into-web-applications/
